# Wrong hWnd pointers when migrating multi-project C++ MFC application from VS6 to VS2013

Tags: c++, mfc, mdi, hwnd, visual-studio-6

We are porting a multi-project C++ MFC application from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2013.

We have encountered run-time errors that affect some of the MDI (multiple document interface) projects within the application.

The hWnd pointers of some of the child windows seem awry; they point incorrectly to other dlls in the solution rather than to the CWnd-derived parent window in the same project.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks. No, we tried that first. And again. And again. No change...

Comment: Is this multithreaded?

Comment: There is some multithreading in the application, but this is not extensive; the application has a number of functional areas that can be openned by the user to run in parallel, and this is where multithreading is used. But within each functional area, operation is singlethreaded.